# Firebase Error: Not allowed to start service Intent act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use `Firebase` push notifications in my App. I followed official documentation and my App works well. I know if `Google Play Services` does not config properly, User can't receive push notifications. Official documents of firebase does not encourage to add new permission line in Manifest.xml. But recently i test my App in emulator and get this error:

```
Not allowed to start service Intent act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER
```

I searched and people say it's about permission and you have to put this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

My question is: This is mandatory? I have to add this permission? if yes, Why Firebase documentations doesn't noted at all!?

My app gets notification if there is `Google Play Services`... But my concern is to cover all types of devices and Operating Systems and I don't want this issue turns a huge problem for me.